# Difference between "function($arg = 0)" and "function($arg)"

Tags: php, dom, function-signature

## Question

In the PHP Official Documentation I found somewhere declarations like this:

```
public int save ( string $filename [, int $options ] )
```

and like this:

```
public mixed load ( string $filename [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

#### What's the difference between both, on the `$options` argument?

The second one I'm sure that has the `$options` argument set to *0* (when I don't specify it).
But the first one? Isn't it saying that the method has 2 mandatory arguments? (so whats the square brackets for?).

## Example

I'm trying to override this:

```
public bool schemaValidate ( string $filename [, int $flags ] )
```

*(fingerprint pasted from [schemaValidate() PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php))*

but if I declare the second argument `$flags`, then I get a

> SchemaValidate() should be compatible with DOMDocument::schemaValidate($filename)

If I remove the declaration of `$flags` everything works (like if I were in **<** *PHP 5.5.2*)

While I run *PHP 5.5.9* and `$flags` has been introduced in `schemaValidate()` constructor from *PHP 5.5.2*, why do I get the incompatibly problem?

I don't get **if the PHP Documentation is trustable or if I should check somewhere else** for the right function fingerprint, when I want to override native methods.

I tried to have a look at the source code, but [the function is merely an alias to a *C* function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fc33f52d8c25997dd0711de3e07d0dc260a18c11/ext/dom/document.c#L228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public int save ( string $filename [, int $options ] )
```

means that the `$options` is *optional*, if you do not pass `$options`, its default value is *null*

```
public mixed load ( string $filename [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

means that the `$options` is *optional*, if you do not pass `$options`, its default value is *0*

To achieve the first documentation, they must have made a function and override them by themselves, as follows:

```
public int save ( string $filename ){
    //do some stuff...
}

//later in code...

public int save ( string $filename, int $options ){
    //do some stuff...
}
```

While in the second one, they just did something like:

```
public mixed load ( string $filename, int $options = 0 ){
    //do some stuff...
}
```

Comment: It's what I thought. But then I asked myself: _since when PHP can declare an optional parameter without specifying a default value?_ How can I do it?

Comment: simply by overriding the function. See my edited answer

Comment: Ok, your updates make sense and probably is an already overridden function. But what if I want to define a _new_ function that has an **optional parameter**, but without specifying its default value? -- `function foo($bar)`, if called like `echo foo()` will tell me that it expects 1 argument. If I do `function foo($bar = 0)` and then `echo foo()` it will work. Is it possible to get the case where the call will just pass `null` as the parameter value (talking outside of the _overriding_ context)?

Comment: Moreover I checked the PHP github repository and the only declaration of `schemaValidate` is in that alias (see link in my question), and I don't see any function overriding. (but Github code search is not working always good, so could be that I'm missing some code)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I got busy that night and forgot about the question. Actually, you can achieve what you need by two ways, make a function `foo($bar)`, override it by `foo()`, and inside `foo(){ foo(null); }` ... simple :) ... to make it simpler, PHP has `foo($bar = null)`

Comment: Ok, no real native straight way to do it. 
Thanks for answering!

Comment: ummm ... this is the exact way how it works in PHP, and this is native. If you are referring something similar to `params` keyword in C#, nop you wont find that in PHP

Comment: No no I don't expect C# :)  The truth is that I was excepting the opposite: that was not possible at all. For that I was quite surprised discovering this possibility with overriding (while I was excepting a _Fatal Error_).